# Connect QGIS web client with GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, qgis-web-client

I installed QGIS server and QGIS web client, and I can see

localhost/web/site/qgiswebclient.html?map=/var/www/web/projects/helloworld.qgs&format=image/png&visibleLayers=Hello,Country

[image]

And I installed PostgreSQL, PostGIS, and geoserver. i connected import shape files and i see

localhost:8080/geoserver/GIStest/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=GIStest:Country&styles=&bbox=-176.248494673366,-67.5929956881973,182.893410989597,83.6210855559975&width=783&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

[image]

**How to read qgis web client from geoserver wms?**

Comment: can you guys vote up. i will add image

Comment: just past a link to the image and we'll add it for you

Comment: Did you mean to say you want the Geoserver map to look like the QGIS map?